# web3.js convert hex value to string

Tags: web3js, dapps, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I use web3.js to read all events and I get the return values when convert this field to original string (string indexed name) original name like mmmm the hex retrund is ("0x112f105bcd1b36ffb28f1725fb287832340e8853e2607a9e9945d200d7c0899e")
I use web3.utils to convert the hex to string web3.utils.hexToAscii("0x112f105bcd1b36ffb28f1725fb287832340e8853e2607a9e9945d200d7c0899e") it returns /[Í6ÿ²%û(x24Sâ`zEÒ×À

smart contract
event play(uint indexed id,string indexed name);

lib ver I used
"web3": "^1.3.0"

can anyone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: "I get the return values" - what return values, and how exactly are you getting them?

Comment: @goodvibration thanks for your comment, the retruned value is "0x42fae273ea147f4212fa0a61b4e202a89aae256d29144500f84cfafcf96201bd" and this should be "Abu Dhabi" when convert to string but I get "BúâsêBú↵a´â¨®%m)EøLúüùb½"

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/VL6ohBq.png

Comment: What do you even mean "return value"? I don't see a single function in your code, so what exactly is "returning a value" here???

Comment: when you call contract.getPastEvents() this will return returnValues to you has all events   info. so from this  returnValues like returnValues.name this will return to you value of name in hex format so I need to convert hex to Ascii

Comment: you can have a look at this https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-contract.html#getpastevents